# SQL : How to know if a set of values exist in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, set

I must import lines from a file into database. I must check if foreign key exists. Here a sample of lines I should import :

```
A   481 11/23/1981  12  77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   482 11/23/1981  15  77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098    
A   482 11/23/1981  12  77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  9   77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  12  77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  12  77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  1   77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  1   77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  1   77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
A   481 11/23/1981  1   77000   DESCRIPTION_1     $5,098
```

Here the foreign key are 12, 15, 9, 12, 1. I want to check if one of these foreign key. In the sample the foreign key 12 does not exist.  The simplest way is to test line by line :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) From TypeTable WHERE IdType = 12 -- 0
SELECT COUNT(*) From TypeTable WHERE IdType = 15 -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) From TypeTable WHERE IdType = 9  -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) From TypeTable WHERE IdType = 12 -- 1
SELECT COUNT(*) From TypeTable WHERE IdType = 1  -- 1
```

The problem with this method is that there is one query for each different foreign key, and files I should import has thousands lines (and potentially thousands foreign key).

So I want to know if it's possible to use the "set feature of SQL" to retrieve in one query but I don't know how to do this...

PS : In the result of my query, I need to know the foreign key does not exist in database

Regards,

Florian

Comment: No. I'm searching for what is a staging table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data has been loaded into a staging table then you can use this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   myStagingTable ST
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM TypeTable TT
            WHERE ST.FKCol = TT.IdType)
```

To do something set based, you need a table with the desired FK values. This could be a temp table on the same connection and populated by scanning the file. The same SQL would work above by changing `myStagingTable` to `#myFKTable`

Answer (score 3):

I would bulk load the data into a temporary staging table in the database, and then it becomes a simple case of running a SELECT with an outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ForeignKeyField
FROM YourStagingTable s
    LEFT JOIN FKTable f ON s.ForeignKeyField = f.ID
WHERE f.ID IS NULL -- where the foreign key value does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameterise your query and pass the foreign key as a parameter?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TypeTable WHERE IdType = @foreignKey)
```

If you put this into a function, you can use the `CROSS APPLY` command to call into the function for each row of a set.